# Parsing logfile using regex in pig

Tags: regex, hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

I need to parse the below log file where in the script should consider from the start of the timestamp `150324-21:06:32:937378` till the start of the next timestamp as one record. i tried using library

```
org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.MyRegExLoader
```

to load the records in custom format.

```
150324-21:06:32:937378 [mod=STB, lvl=INFO ]
    top - 21:06:33 up  3:41,  0 users,  load average: 0.75, 0.95, 0.72
    Tasks: 120 total,   3 running, 117 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
    Cpu(s): 21.8%us, 12.9%sy,  2.9%ni, 60.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  1.7%si,  0.0%st
    Mem:    317108k total,   232588k used,    84520k free,    25960k buffers
    Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,   110820k cached
      PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND            
    19122 root      20   0  456m  72m  37m R   72 23.5  85:50.22 Receiver           
     5859 root      20   0  349m 9128 6948 S   15  2.9  22:42.88 rmfStreamer
     150324-21:06:32:937378 [mod=STB, lvl=INFO ]
    top - 21:06:33 up  3:41,  0 users,  load average: 0.75, 0.95, 0.72
    Tasks: 120 total,   3 running, 117 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
    Cpu(s): 21.8%us, 12.9%sy,  2.9%ni, 60.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  1.7%si,  0.0%st
    Mem:    317108k total,   232588k used,    84520k free,    25960k buffers
    Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,   110820k cached
      PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND            
    19122 root      20   0  456m  72m  37m R   72 23.5  85:50.22 Receiver           
     5859 root      20   0  349m 9128 6948 S   15  2.9  22:42.88 rmfStreamer
```

here is my relevant code snippet i used

```
raw_logs = LOAD './main*/*top_log*'   USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.MyRegExLoader('(?m)(?s)\\d*-\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\:\\d*.*') AS line:chararray ; DUMP raw_logs;
```

here is my output:

```
(150325-05:47:26:253050 [mod=STB, lvl=INFO ])
(150325-05:57:27:294069 [mod=STB, lvl=INFO ])
(150325-06:07:28:235302 [mod=STB, lvl=INFO ])
(150325-06:17:29:124282 [mod=STB, lvl=INFO ])
(150325-06:27:30:036264 [mod=STB, lvl=INFO ])
(150325-06:37:30:941804 [mod=STB, lvl=INFO ])
(150325-06:47:31:909712 [mod=STB, lvl=INFO ])
```

It should be like in 2 tuples

```
(150324-21:06:32:937378 [mod=STB, lvl=INFO ]
top - 21:06:33 up  3:41,  0 users,  load average: 0.75, 0.95, 0.72
Tasks: 120 total,   3 running, 117 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 21.8%us, 12.9%sy,  2.9%ni, 60.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  1.7%si,  0.0%st
Mem:    317108k total,   232588k used,    84520k free,    25960k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,   110820k cached
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND            
19122 root      20   0  456m  72m  37m R   72 23.5  85:50.22 Receiver           
 5859 root      20   0  349m 9128 6948 S   15  2.9  22:42.88 rmfStreamer)
(150324-21:06:32:937378 [mod=STB, lvl=INFO ]
top - 21:06:33 up  3:41,  0 users,  load average: 0.75, 0.95, 0.72
Tasks: 120 total,   3 running, 117 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 21.8%us, 12.9%sy,  2.9%ni, 60.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  1.7%si,  0.0%st
Mem:    317108k total,   232588k used,    84520k free,    25960k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,   110820k cached
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND            
19122 root      20   0  456m  72m  37m R   72 23.5  85:50.22 Receiver           
 5859 root      20   0  349m 9128 6948 S   15  2.9  22:42.88 rmfStreamer)
```

Please let me know the regex expression i can use so that my script consider the start of the timestamp till the start of the next timestamp one record.

Answer (score 0):

Try the match group of the following regex:

```
([0-9]{6}-[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]+ \[mod=[\s\S]*)[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]+ \[mod=
```

Comment: Thanks uri. I tried it but it is not working i am not getting any matches using the above expression.

Answer (score 0):

i dont think it is possible using pig.
You will need a custom record reader which uses regex  for splitting the file as per the timestamp of the first record.

I hope the below link will help you to write one
https://hadoopi.wordpress.com/2013/05/31/custom-recordreader-processing-string-pattern-delimited-records/

you might have to tweak some logic of it to get the time stamp per line

```
if (m.matches()) {
        // Record delimiter
        delimiterString=tmp;
        break;
    } else {
        // Append value to record

        text.append(EOL.getBytes(), 0, EOL.getLength());
        text.append(tmp.getBytes(), 0, tmp.getLength());
        text.append(delimiterString.getBytes(), 0, delimiterString.getLength() );
    }
```

result will appear as below
 top - 02:10:39 up 0 min,  0 users,  load average: 2.26, 0.54, 0.18150323-02:10:37:619962 [mod=STB, lvl=INFO ]
Tasks: 133 total,   6 running, 127 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie150323-02:10:37:619962 [mod=STB, lvl=INFO ]

Comment: regular expression will be this.delimiterRegex ="^[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{6}.*$";